# Selected index of one dropdownlist setting all dropdownlists on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a webpage with 4 dropdownlists on the page. In the page load method I have the code behind set the values of the dropdownlists. The problem is that when I set any one of the dropdownlists it sets all of the dropdownlists.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //populating the dropdownlist with values
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                ListItem temp = new ListItem(i + "");
                ddl_EndMin.Items.Add(temp);
                ddl_StartMin.Items.Add(temp);
                if (i < 24)
                {
                    ddl_EndHour.Items.Add(temp);
                    ddl_StartHour.Items.Add(temp);
                }
            }

            //Setting the dropdownlists with the values from the conference variable
            ddl_EndHour.SelectedIndex = conference.EndDate.Hour;
            ddl_StartMin.SelectedIndex = conference.StartDate.Minute;
            ddl_StartHour.SelectedIndex = conference.StartDate.Hour;
            ddl_EndMin.SelectedIndex = conference.EndDate.Minute;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why setting one of these dropdownlists selected index sets all of them. I also tried replacing one of them with a ListBox and the value of the ListBox was set as well. There is code on another page that sets 2 dropdownlists using this selected index method but using states instead of numbers and that works just fine.

```
ddl_EndMin.SelectedIndex = ddl_EndMin.Items.IndexOf(ddl_EndMin.Items.FindByValue(conference.EndDate.Minute.ToString()));
ddl_EndHour.SelectedIndex = ddl_EndHour.Items.IndexOf(ddl_EndHour.Items.FindByValue(conference.EndDate.Hour.ToString()));
```

I tried copy/pasting that code into what I'm currently working on and changing the names and I got the same results. Any insight you can give me as to why this problem is occuring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you also post the code where you add items to the dropdowns?

Comment: Have you subscribed to SelectedIndexChanged event of the drop down list control? Guess you have some code there.

Comment: I have not used the SelectedIndexChanged event of the drop down list control. No code there :/

Comment: @user2433766 I think the entire thing should be in a !IsPostBack, you're filling the dropdown list each time you load the page.Try wrapping the for loop in the !IsPostBack as well

Comment: @MyName You're right, sorry, when I added in the code for shriek I accidently pasted it outside of the if statement.

Comment: @user2433766 Is it possible for us to see one or two of the ddl declarations ? (The markup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess it's because you're using the same item collection in all of your dropdowns.

Then when you set the `selected` property on one of the items it has that property in all of your lists as it's the same object reference in all lists.

What happens if you do this within the loop

```
            ListItem temp = new ListItem(i + "");
            ddl_EndMin.Items.Add(temp);
            temp = new ListItem(i + "");
            ddl_StartMin.Items.Add(temp);
            if (i < 24)
            {
                temp = new ListItem(i + "");
                ddl_EndHour.Items.Add(temp);
                temp = new ListItem(i + "");
                ddl_StartHour.Items.Add(temp);
            }
```

Comment: @Klors I don't think it matters that each dropdown list has the same item collection. When you set the selected item of a dropdown you use that particular control

Comment: Yep, a quick test of creating multiple for loops fixed the problem. Is there a more efficient way to populate the dropdowns besides 4 for loops?

Comment: Take a look at my edit, you just need a fresh `ListItem` before adding it to the item collection. You can do that all in the same loop then.

Comment: @Klors Whatever works lol :D ... Ahh Kay.. I read your answer again. I'll have to try it out myself

Comment: The `ListItem` is an instance of a class, when you add it to the Items collection of the `DropDownList` it is added `by reference`, not `by value`. Then when it has its selected property set to true, it is the same in each list as it's actually the same reference to the `ListItem` in each list.

Comment: Is there a way to add by value?

Comment: You could `.Clone()` it, but it's much easier to just create a fresh `ListItem` each time.

Comment: Hmm.. turned out `SelectedIndex` property will loop through all items and invoke `.Selected` property of the listItem at that index. Cool.. +1

Comment: Yeah, it's because the `ListItem` is the same one that can be used in `ListBox` controls where you can have multiple `ListItem`s selected at once, so the `Selected` property is on the `ListItem` itself. It caught me out when I accidentally managed to set 2 items as selected at once, which breaks things. :)